# Cannot load a graph in OSMnx

Tags: python, osmnx

I am trying to compute the driving distance between two points using OSMnx in Python:

```py
import osmnx as ox

G = ox.graph_from_place("Piedmont, California, USA", network_type="drive")
```

However, when running this code I get the following error:

```
/Users/luismoncayo/anaconda3/envs/Hope/lib/python3.11/site-packages/shapely/constructive.py:181: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in buffer
  return lib.buffer(
/Users/luismoncayo/anaconda3/envs/Hope/lib/python3.11/site-packages/shapely/predicates.py:798: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in intersects
  return lib.intersects(a, b, **kwargs)
/Users/luismoncayo/anaconda3/envs/Hope/lib/python3.11/site-packages/shapely/set_operations.py:340: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in union
  return lib.union(a, b, **kwargs)
/Users/luismoncayo/anaconda3/envs/Hope/lib/python3.11/site-packages/shapely/predicates.py:798: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in intersects
  return lib.intersects(a, b, **kwargs)
/Users/luismoncayo/anaconda3/envs/Hope/lib/python3.11/site-packages/shapely/set_operations.py:340: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in union
  return lib.union(a, b, **kwargs)
```

Can anyone suggest how to solve this issue?

Comment: Working on MacOS M1 Pro (OSMnx 1.4.0)

Comment: I'm seeing some warnings but no errors. What do you mean "cannot load"? It looks like it did.

Comment: See also https://github.com/shapely/shapely/issues/1709

Answer (score 0):

I installed the package OSMnx from the conda console, which solved the problem.